# Additional assumptions on function to ensure uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Given a sequence $u=(u_n)_{n\geq1}$ converging to $1$, I would like to prove uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n$ defined by $f_n(x)=f(u_n x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ to the function $f$, where $f$ satisfies a certain number of assumptions to be determined.

I have already thought about $f$ being $C^1$ and bounded for example, but this doesn't seem to work as I can still find some counter-examples based on trigonometric functions.

I guess my question would therefore be: what are the least constraining assumptions having to be made on $f$ (and maybe even on $u$) which would ensure uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$? Does the assumption of bounded first derivative suffice (as per comment below)?

Comment: I dont think that "the least constraining assumptions" exists. A somewhat boring sufficient condition is $f \in C_0(\mathbb R_+)$ (continuous and $f(x)\to 0$ for $x\to \infty$). You can get different sufficient conditions from $f(x)-f(u_nx) = \int_{u_n}^1 f'(tx)xdt$.

Comment: @Jochen, thanks for that. I was wondering how you obtained the vanishing at infinity condition from the integral representation above? And what are the other sufficient conditions one can obtain?

Comment: I think that you can get a variety of more or less independent sufficient conditions. Vanishing at infinity and bounds on $f'$ are not directly related.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is the bounded first derivative condition sufficient? If I write $\sup_{x\geq0}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\geq0}|\int_{u_n}^1 f'(tx)xdt|\leq \|f'\|(1-u_n) \sup_{x\geq0} x$, how can I conclude?

Comment: @Jochen, if we take $n\rightarrow \infty$ above, don't we get an undetermined limit (i.e zero times infinity)?

Comment: Apparently, boundedness of $f'$ is not enough.

Comment: The formula $f(x)-f(u_nx)=\int_{u_n}^1 f'(tx)xdt$ is not yet a condition, but it shows that, e.g., boundedness of  $|f'(x) x|$ would be sufficient.

Comment: @Jochen ok I see now. But where does the vanishing at infinity sufficient condition come from?